# Derivative as a rate measurer

Tags: geometry, derivatives, applications

I studied about the application of derivatives as *they help in measuring rate of change*.
For example :-

Let $A$ be area of a circle of radius $r$

$$A = \pi \cdot r^2$$

then

$$\frac {dA}{dr}= 2 \pi \cdot r $$

Suppose we have to find rate of change of area w.r.t to radius 
at $r = 5 \text{ cm}$ .

Then

$$\left(\frac {dA}{dr}\right)_{r=5}= 10 \pi\text{ cm}^2/\text{cm} $$

My question is:

Does our final answer mean that when the radius of the circle changes from $5 \text{cm}$ to $6 \text{cm}$, the change in area is equal to $ 10\pi\text{cm}^2 $,
i.e., the area of circle at $6 \text{cm} = \text{area of circle at }5 \text{cm} + 10\pi\ \text{cm}^2 $?

Comment: But area $A$ at $6 \text { cm}$ is $\pi 36 \text  { cm}^2$ while area at $5 \text { cm}$ is $\pi 25 \text { cm}^2$

Comment: Not quite. It means that when the radius of the circle changes from $5\ \rm cm$ to $(5+\epsilon)\ \rm cm$, the area of the circle changes by approximately $10\pi\epsilon\ \rm cm^2$, and the approximation is more accurate the smaller $\epsilon$ is. In your example, $\epsilon=1$, which is not very small, so the estimated change in area, $10\pi\ \rm cm^2$, is only moderately close to the actual change of area, $11\pi\ \rm cm^2$.

Comment: @Rahul what does the answer that I calculated actually means ?

Comment: Your $10\pi cm^2/cm$ is often called a "_first order approximation_". More correctly, together with the information $A(5) = 25\pi$, it is $A(6)\approx 25\pi + 10\pi$ which is a first order approximation of $A(6)$. It is the best approximation to $A(6)$ that you can make knowing only $A(5)$ and $A'(5)$.

Comment: @JIM  Please recall that if the OP is solved you can evaluate to accept an answer among the given, more details [HERE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Answer (score 3):

All the previous answers explained the problem quite well. But according to your comment on these answer, you still have trouble understanding when to your approximation holds. I'll try to explain what values of h are acceptable to use your method.

Let's call $A(r)$ the area of a circle of radius $r$. We have $A_{real}=\color{blue}{\pi*r²}$

If $h$ is small enough, you can have $A_{approx}(r_0+h) \approx \color{red}{A(r_0)+2*\pi*r_0*h}$

But keep in mind that the real value of $A(r_0+h)$ is indeed:

\begin{align}A_{real}(r_0+h)=\color{blue}{\pi*(r_0+h)²}\\
& =\pi*({r_0}²+2r_0h+h²)\\
& =\color{blue}{\pi*{r_0}²}+2*\pi*r_0*h+\pi*h²\\
& =\color{red}{A_{real}(r_0)+2*\pi*r_0*h}+\pi*h² \\
& =\color{red}{A_{approx}(r_0+h)} +\pi*h²
\end{align}

From there, the [relative error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Approximation_error) between you result and the real one is:

$$E=\frac{A_{real}(r_0+h)-A_{approx}(r_0+h)}{A_{real}(r_0+h)}$$
$$E=\frac{\pi*h²}{\pi*(r_0+h)²}$$
$$E=\frac{h²}{(r_0+h)²}$$

So, you can see that as $h/r_0 \rightarrow 0$, the error $E \rightarrow 0$ too.

This means that as soon as $h/r_0$ is small enough, so is your error. Let see it this way, if you change 1cm in diameter on a circle of 10cm, and calculate the new area with your initial idea, your error will be more important that if you change 1cm on a 1m diameter circle. What only matter **in this case** is that the change is small enough versus the initial diameter.

The problem in your question is that you chose $h=1$ and $r_0=5$. You'll need $h$ to be smaller or $r_0$ to be greater

I made some calculation for circles of radius 5cm, 10cm, and 1m ($r_0=5,10,100$), with a changing radius of 1cm, you have errors of respectively: $2.7\%$,$0.8\%$ and $0.01\%$ between the real area and the one calculated from your formula.

Comment: you really answered the question well !! And I am able to understand most part of question except from "From There . the relative error .............. is small enough , so is your error ."

Comment: I edited so it may appear clearer. Anyway, I just wrote this as a side answer because you kept asking if you $h$ was small enough. Please note that the whole $h/r_0$ thing is really specific to THAT case. The general reason why derivative can't be used that way is covered by other answers

Comment: what i meant to ask was that how did you get the formula for E=Areal(r0+h)−Aapprox(r0+h)Areal(r0+h)

Comment: My bad. It's the basic formula for [relative error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Approximation_error#Formal_Definition). I Added the link in the main body.

Comment: one more thing , after the calculation of error comes out to be E=h²/(r0+h)^2  , how do you get to know that as h/r0 tends to zero . E tends to 0 ??

Comment: I lack the vocabulary to explain it in a very formal way (not a native speaker), but you can see it this way: when $h \lt \lt r_0$ ($h$ way smaller that $r_0$), you have $r_0+h \approx r_0$. So $E \approx h² / {r_0}²$.  From there, $E \rightarrow 0²=0$. For more information, you can read about [limits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_of_a_function)

Comment: what i want to ask is that how does E=h²/(r0+h)^2 become E = h^2/ro^2 ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/82725/discussion-between-f-carette-and-jim).

Answer (score 2):

We should write

$$\frac {dA}{d\color{red}r}= 2 \pi \cdot r$$

No of course our final answer doaes not mean that when radius of circle changes from $5 cm$ to $6 cm$ then the change in area is equal to $10\pi\ cm^2$, indeed derivatives are linear approximation and, since in that case the relationship between $A$ and $r$ is not linear, it means that

$$\Delta A \approx 10\pi \Delta r$$

and the approximation becomes better for smaller $\Delta r$.

Comment: does this mea that derivatives hold true best for linear approximation ? Also what is Linear approximation ?

Comment: @JIM Yes exactly for a differentiable function they are the bestlinear approximation, that means that we are approximating locally the function with its tangent line at that point. By Taylor's expansion we can get better approximation using higher order terms.

Answer (score 2):

No, but the intuition is correct.

$\frac{dA}{dr}$ is the *instantaneous* rate of change at radius $r$. It means that if your radius is initially $r_0$ (say, 5cm), and you increase the radius by an infinitesimally small amount $dr$, the change in area will be given by $\frac{dA}{dr}$ evaluated at $r_0$. At the new point $r_0 + dr$, the rate of change of area might be different (as it is in this case, where $\frac{dA}{dr}$ depends on $r$. However, if your change in radius is small, your idea could be a good approximation for the change in area.

However, a larger change in area can be viewed as an aggregation of many small infinitesimal changes to $r$. This can be expressed as an integral, and so, the area change when you change the radius from $r_0$ to $r_0+1$ is given by
$$\int_{r_0}^{r_0+1} \left(\frac{dA}{dr}\right) dr$$

It could be the case for some functions that the derivative is independent of $r$. In such a case, your idea will give exactly the correct answer, as the rate of change will not change with $r$. An example of such a function would be the rate of change of circumference of a circle with respect to the radius.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is true, but only for variations such that the linear approximation is acceptable.

For an increase of the radius of $0.001$ cm, the increase in area is approximated by$10\cdot\pi\cdot0.001=0.0314159265\cdots$

Compare to the exact value $\pi(5.001^2-5^2)=0.0314190681\cdots$

In green, the linear approximation.

[image]

Comment: so does that mean if we take the change in radius tending to zero ,  we would start getting more accurate value ?

Comment: @JIM: this is what the plot illustrates.

Comment: What does the answer that I calculated actually means ?

Comment: @JIM: which one ?

Comment: the answer that I calculated in the question

Comment: @JIM: namely ??

Comment: $$10\pi cm^2$$ .....

Comment: @JIM But... that's the rate of change( which is not in $cm^2$).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/82672/discussion-between-jim-and-yves-daoust).

Comment: @JIM It is the slope of the green line in the graph.

Answer (score 2):

Let$f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrowtail \mathbb{R}$ be a function, and $a \in \text{Int}(\text{dom}(f))$. Then the following statements are equivalent:

- $f$ is differentiable at $a$
- $\exists \xi \in \mathbb{R}$ and $\exists \eta: \text{dom}(f) \to \mathbb{R}$ with $\lim\limits_{x \to a} \frac{\eta(x)}{x-a}=0$, so that
  $$f(x)=f(a)+\xi(x-a)+\eta(x)$$
  and $\xi=f'(a)$.

I think this equivalent definition of differentiability is more spectacular (and it's easier to generalize to the $\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrowtail \mathbb{R}^m$ case), because we can intuitively see that $\eta(x)$ is really small around $a$, so for $x \approx a$ we have that
$$f(x) \approx f(a) + \xi(x-a)$$
In your case, if we let $A(r):=r^2 \pi$, we have that $A'(r)=2r \pi$
$$A(r)=A(r_0)+\xi(r-r_0)+\eta(r)$$
And of course, $\xi=A'(r_0)=2r_0\pi$:
$$A(r)=A(r_0)+2r_0(r-r_0)\pi+\eta(r)$$
$$A(r)=r_0^2 \pi+2r_0(r-r_0)\pi+\eta(r)$$
$$A(r)=r_0^2 \pi+2r_0r\pi-2r_0^2 \pi+\eta(r)$$
$$A(r)=2rr_0 \pi-r_0^2 \pi + \eta(r) \tag{1}$$
If we want to get $\eta(r)$:
$$r^2 \pi=2rr_0 \pi-r_0^2 \pi + \eta(r)$$
$$r^2 \pi+r_0^2\pi-2r r_0 \pi=\eta(r)$$
$$\eta(r)=(r-r_0)^2 \pi$$
Using some numbers, we have that $A(5)=25 \pi$, $A(5.1)=26.01 \pi$, $A(50)=2500 \pi$. If we try to approximate $A(5.1)$ and $A(50)$ with $A(5)$ and $A'(5)$, we can use the first equation (without $\eta(r)$):
$$A(r) \approx 10 r \pi - 25 \pi$$
we get that $A(5.1) \approx 26 \pi$ and $A(50) \approx 475 \pi$, while $\eta(5.1)=0.01 \pi$ and $\eta(50)=2025 \pi$. As you can see, it's quite good for $5.1$, but it's terrible for $50$.

This kind of linear approximation is really useful in physics, for example when you are dealing with a complicated system, you can't really solve the differential equation(s), but you can make the assumption that the change in the sought function (for example, the displacement-time function of a ball) is really small, so you can linearize the equation, and (probably) solve it.

Comment: Maybe the symbol $A$ is a little confusing here.

Comment: @gimusi you're right.

Comment: @Botond not able to understand a single word that you wrote !!

Comment: @JIM I extended my answer.

Answer (score 0):

No, but you are on the right track.

The derivative you have found tells you that when the radius changes from $5$cm to $(5+h)$cm and **$h$ is small** then the area changes by **approximately** $10\pi h$ square cm.

In your example you are taking $h=1$, which is not small, so the approximation isn't even close.

Comment: So what does the answer that I calculated actually means (if it does not mean change in area )??

Comment: What you calculated is the approximation to the change in area you get by substituting $h=1$ in the approximation recipe the derivative provides. Whether that's a good approximation to the change depends on how large the derivative is and how big $h$ is relative to what matters in an application.

Comment: In this case is my *h* correct ??

Comment: There's no such thing as "the correct $h$". The smaller it is the better the approximation.

Answer (score 0):

To say that $\left.\dfrac{dA}{dr}\right|_{r\,=\,5\text{ cm}} = 10\pi\text{ cm}$ means that if you multiply the rate of change of $r,$ at the point at which $r=5\text{ cm},$ by $10\pi\text{ cm},$ you get the rate of change of $A$ at that point. But that does not mean that if $r$ grows by $1\text{ cm},$ then $A$ will increase by $10\pi\text{ cm}^2,$ because it won't continue changing at that same rate as $r$ changes.

Generally if $\left.\dfrac{dy}{dx}\right|_{x\,=\,a} = b$ means that at the point where $x=a,$ the dependent variable $y$ is changing $a$ times as fast as the independent variable $x.$